# Are halflines closed?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Is the following set closed?

$\{x\in R| x\geq a (x\leq a)\}$

To me it is because it contains all its boundary points.

Comment: Yes. Why do you doubt this?

Comment: Yes, because it's complement is open.

Comment: Yes. The Euclidean topology suggests that every open interval is open, the complement of your halfline is $(-\infty,a)$ which is open, hence your set is closed. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does that mean just $\{a\}$? Or is it $[a,+\infty)$ or alternatively $(-\infty,a]$ ?

Comment: The last you mentioned, but would not $\{a\}$ be closed as well?

Comment: Yes $\{a\}$ is closed, as all singleton sets in all metric (or ordered) spaces.